# How to check if current state in ui-router is a child of an abstract state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an abstract state "settings" with a set of children defined using strings, like "settings.personal", "settings.business" and so on. I need to check in a higher level shared controller if current state is a child of abstract "settings" state.

I can't figure out how to check for this? I tried to use `$state.is` hoping it's smart enough to detect this but it seems it's not.

```
$state.is("settings") # => false
$state.is("settings.personal") # => true
```

So, any other idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I now see that there's also `$state.includes` method which does exactly what I wanted.

I'll leave this question for community to judge if it's worth keeping or should it be deleted.

Comment: Great, exactly what I have been looking for. Check `https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference` for more info.